# Storybook type wrong when using children as an arg

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storyboard

I'm trying to use TS and storybook `children` in `args`, https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/stories-for-multiple-components#using-children-as-an-arg

I have a `Button.stories.tsx`:

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from "@storybook/react"

import { Button } from "./Button"

export default {
    title: "Example/Button",
    component: Button,
    argTypes: {
        backgroundColor: { control: "color" },
    },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => <Button {...args} />

export const Primary = Template.bind({})
Primary.args = {
    primary: true,
    label: "Button",
}
```

and `ButtonGroup.stories.tsx`:

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from "@storybook/react"

import { ButtonGroup } from "./ButtonGroup"

import { Primary } from "../Button/Button.stories"

export default {
    title: "Example/ButtonGroup",
    component: ButtonGroup,
    argTypes: {},
}

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof ButtonGroup> = (args) => <ButtonGroup {...args} />

export const PrimaryButtonGroup = Template.bind({})
PrimaryButtonGroup.args = {
    children: (
        <>
            <Primary {...Primary.args} />
            <Primary {...Primary.args} />
        </>
    ),
}
```

There is a type error on the `<Primary {...Primary.args} />` on `PrimaryButtonGroup.args`. The problem is the `args` is optional, so the `primary` and `label` from `Primary.args` could be `undefined`. So it cannot match the label type `string`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hello, I'm having exactly the same issue as you. Did you manage to find a solution in the end?